# How to fix the pdf "Bad 'Length' attribute in stream" issue using MacTex tools?

Tags: pdftex

Scenario: I am generating pdf using [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) from php , where I use a template pdf to 
   fill the form (its static not Fillable) ,I place text in required positions to
   give the feeling of its filled by user. which is working great except size it little 
   extra than expected and pdf are viewable without any error or issues

New Requirement: Now I need to

- merge these files into single file
- create a bookmark to each report generated in first step (create TOC)
- possibility reset the page numbers

Obviously I need an open source tool , I don't find any opensource lib/tool( php /java/commandline ), so I installed MacTex package for pdflatex and realted tool

Whenever I include the pdf generated from php I get the errors below . My question to this great community is how I can fix this issue and what are the chances of merging the pdf files generated from php and add TOC

I have borrowed the tex file from [SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3378/modifying-pdf-files)  by @captaincomic

**Tex**

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\topmargin 70pt
\oddsidemargin 150pt

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\Large\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{include_file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

**> pdflatex  number.tex**

**Output Error**

```
  ....
    <include_file.pdf, id=3, page=1, 614.295pt x 794.97pt>
    <use include_file.pdf, page 1> <use include_file.pdf, page 1>
    <use include_file.pdf, page 1> <use include_file.pdf, page 1>
    <use include_file.pdf, page 1> [1{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/p
    dftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./include_file.pdfError (2874915): Bad 'Length' attribute in stream

    !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./include_file.pdf): PDF inclusion: type <error> 
    cannot be copied
     ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

[PDF file](http://www.filedropper.com/includefile)

Comment: The error message doesn't come from TeX, but from the library (probably `xpdf`) which does the pdf inclusion. I assume the pdf to be included is really broken. Have you tried to open/process it with another tool? Maybe you could make the file available for inspection?

Comment: @StephanLehmke thanks to drop a comment. Would you suggest how I can inspect the pdf file ? The file is viewable perfectly  in Acrobat ,and other pdf viewers. thanks

Comment: That the file displays without error in acrobat isn't a good sign because it might mean there is a bug in the pdf library used by pdftex :-( What I meant by making the file available was to upload it somewhere so people could look at it for the reason of the inclusion error.

Comment: I ll ask my client . However,using tip: http://thomer.com/howtos/embed_font_in_pdf.html. I reduced the size of pdf files.After merging the pdf using  FPDF_TPL: http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/downloads/ . when I try to run any of pdf* command e.g pdf2ps I get the following error : `Error: /typecheck in --run--
Operand stack:
   --dict:5/14(L)--   F2   14.12   --dict:5/5(L)--   --dict:5/5(L)--   DejaVuSans-Bold-UCS` . This seems to be embeded font issue. As I am using DejaVu fonts .

Comment: It seems I have to subscribe to something to access the file...

Comment: please check it again : http://www.filedropper.com/includefile , sorry for the previous link

Comment: While `pdfinfo` shows no problem on the file, `pdffonts` lists many `Invalid CIDToGIDMap entry in CID font` errors (`Bad 'Length' attribute in stream`).

Comment: @egreg what do you suggest , how this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I successfully repaired `include_file.pdf` using the command line tool `pdftk`:

```
pdftk include_file.pdf output include_file_fixed.pdf
```

or command line tool `qpdf`:

```
qpdf include_file.pdf include_file_fixed.pdf
```

Both tools recompress all stream objects within a PDF file, thereby renewing the value of the `/Length` entry in the associated stream dictionary of the stream object. `qpdf` reports wrong `\Length` values in 12 stream objects.

With the fixed file the error disappears.

Comment: thanks to point out that , but I don't think I ll able to use that due to licensing restrictions. I need an "Free Open Source" solution that does not have licensing restrictions. To my knowledge pdftk is based on iText and iText is fairly limited for commercial applications. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks again

Comment: @sakhunzai: pdftk is GPL and iText is AGPL. Where is the problem?

Comment: @sakhunzai: qpdf is Artistic License. Does this fit?

Comment: I am not expert in this domain but the iText licence page says `Buying such a license is mandatory as soon as you develop commercial activities distributing the iText software inside your product or deploying it on a network without disclosing the source code of your own applications under the AGPL license. These activities include: offering paid services to customers as an ASP, serving PDFs on the fly in the cloud or in a web application, shipping iText with a closed source product.`

Comment: qpdf licence seems to be reasonable  `Distributor Fees are permitted, and licensing fees for other components in the aggregation are permitted. The terms of this license apply to the use and Distribution of the Standard or Modified Versions as included in the aggregation.` Do you think `qpdf` can solve this issue ?

Comment: @sakhunzai I don't see why the license of `pdftk` wouldn't allow you to *use* the program to do its job. You're not redistributing the program or making it available in an application.

Comment: Yippee!  I just had a PDF file with a bad stream length (my own fault, I manually modified it) and wanted to fix it without having to count bytes.  Google led me straight here and `pdftk` fixed my PDF.  (Admittedly, it was `pdftk` that made it possible for me to mess it up in the first place as well ...).  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @egreg my application is supposed to be web-based application running in cloud setup e.g ` deploying it on a network without disclosing the source code`

Comment: @sakhunzai But are you actually going to recompile a PDF tool that does something similar to pdftk or are you just going to pipe the PDF through pdftk at some point?  I didn't follow everything here, but isn't it just the original PDF that is broken so fix that once, and you're done.

Comment: @sakhunzai Moreover, I'm puzzled.  You wanted an open source solution (says so in the question) and yet you won't release the source code of your application (that's the only conclusion I can draw from you saying that you have to buy an iText license).

Comment: @Andrew Stacey  this is not one time process , I am building web-application that will do this task as per request for our clients , Step1 : PHP( generate pdf files reports ) , Step2: merg pdf files , add bookmark etc ..

Comment: @sakhunzai So the *generated* files are broken?  Sounds like you should fix the generator then!  Are you really adverse to publishing your source code?  If not, there's no problem.  Are you running `pdftk` *as is*?  If so, there's no problem.  The only time there's a problem is if you want to create a new program based on the iText library but don't want to publish the source code anywhere.

Comment: That is the case , I don't ( actually my client) don't want to publish source code ( PHP +bash script that will fix this issue).

Comment: @sakhunzai But if the source code is just PHP + bash then you *can't* be recompiling the iText suite and must just be using `pdftk` from within the bash script.  In which case, you're not dealing with iText directly and so don't need to concern yourself with its licence.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3535/discussion-between-sakhunzai-and-andrew-stacey)